# $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx <\infty \Rightarrow \exists \{a_n \} \subset [0,\infty) ; \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R $ be continuous and nonnegative $(\forall x\in [0, \infty); f(x)\geqq 0)$.

Then, prove that
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx <\infty \\ \Longrightarrow \exists \{a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset [0,\infty) ; \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =\infty \mathrm{\ and \ } \lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n)=0.$$

Hint : Consider $b_n=\int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx$ for $n=0,1,2,\cdots$

---

Using the hint, I got $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n =0$ from $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx <\infty$, and I think this is useful for solving this problem. But I'm stacked here. If I let $a_n=\frac{1}{b_n}$, then $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n=\infty$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n)=0$ doesn't seem to be proved. I don't know what I should do.

I'd like you to give me any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By continuity $\int_n^{n+1} f(t)dt=f(a_n)$ for some $a_n \in [n, n+1]$ (since the integral has  a value between the maximum and the minimum value of $f$ in $[n,n+1]$).